# iOS: SKProductRequest returns all product ids as invalid when running in development environment

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8

In the last week i am unable to retrieve list of products using SKProductsRequest. Same request exactly runs great in production but does not work in dev. I am not sure what to do and am afraid to upload new version to production because i fear it will also stop working in production.

I tested both xCode and uploading to test flight (in both cases tested on several devices).

Recently my itunes connect subscription was renewed. Can the issue be related to the renew operation?

Comment: 'does not work in dev' you mean not working in simulator? or not in even device. purchases works good in devices. simulator have problem most of the time. Do you have valid certificates? Have you tried testing it through test flight release before going live?

Comment: Does not work when running from xCode or test flight version on a device.

Comment: Did you check if there is some pending acceptance of license agreement? for a quick test of account subscription issue you can change bundle of app to some other app and create and buy a test product from that account using same code.

Comment: Yes, i made sure all my subscriptions are approved. Same code also works perfectly in the app store version.

Comment: and you have same bundle for store and adhoc distribution? parameters looks fine perhaps it is issue of account renewal.

Comment: If there some known issue with renewing account? Anything i should do?

Comment: could you please try rebooting device and log out then login as suggested here : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7463219?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Tried all these tricks. I also tried it on 6 devices

Comment: Are you sure you are running the sandbox env ?

Comment: What do you mean by "running the sandbox env"? I am only requesting, not making any purchase. When i make a purchase i use sandbox users

Comment: as i suggested earlier "for a quick test of account subscription issue you can change bundle of app to some other app and create and buy a test product from that account using same code." this way you will be sure the issue is only with account.